Simple recursion for the A329369 using Stirling numbers of both kinds
Let $s(n,k)$ be a (signed) Stirling number of the first kind.
Let $n \brace k$ be a Stirling number of the second kind.

Let $a(n)$ be A329369 (i.e, number of permutations of ${1,2,...,m}$ with excedance set constructed by taking $m-i$ ($0 < i < m$) if $b(i-1) = 1$ where $b(k)b(k-1)\cdots b(1)b(0)$ ($0 \leqslant k < m-1$) is the binary expansion of $n$). Here

$$
a(2^m(2k+1)) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{m}\binom{m+1}{j}a(2^jk), \\
a(0) = 1
$$
I conjecture that
$$
a(2^m(2^n(2k+1) - 1)) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m+1}a(2^i k)(-1)^{m-i+1} \sum\limits_{j=i}^{m+1}j^n s(j,i) {m+1 \brace j}, \\
a(0) = 1.
$$
Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:
a(n) = my(A = 2*n+1, B, C, v1, v2); v1 = []; while(A > 0, B=valuation(A, 2); v1=concat(v1, B+1); A \= 2^(B+1)); v1 = Vecrev(v1); A = #v1; v2 = vector(A, i, 1);  for(i=1, A-1, B = A-i; for(j=1, B, C = B-j+2; v2[j] = v2[j]*C^v1[B] - v2[j+1]*(C-1)^v1[B])); v2[1]
f(n,m,k) = sum(i=1, m+1, a1(2^i*k)*(-1)^(m-i+1)*sum(j=i, m+1, j^n*stirling(j, i, 1)*stirling(m+1, j, 2)))
a1(n) = if(n == 0, 1, my(A = valuation(n, 2), n = n >> A, B = valuation(n+1, 2), C = (n+1) >> (B+1)); f(B, A, C))
test(n) = a(n) == a1(n)

Note that second sum multiplied by $(-1)^{m-i+1}$ is always positive.
Is there a way to prove it?
